# Retriving the row index of edited cell in <p:dataTable> with <p:rowEditor>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When using `<p:rowEditor>`, how can I retrieve the row index of the edited cell?

Here is the relevant code:

```
<p:dataTable id="datasetParamDt" var="datasetParam" value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.allParametersList}" editable="true" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">  
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit"  listener="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.onParameterValueEdit}" update=":campaignForm:growl" />  
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.onParameterValueCancel}" update=":campaignForm:growl"/>  

    <p:column headerText="Value">  
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output"> 
                <h:outputText value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.paramValue}" />
            </f:facet> 
            <f:facet name="input"> 
                <p:inputText value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.paramValue}" /> 
            </f:facet>     
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column> 

    <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">  
        <p:rowEditor />
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>
```

In simple datatables I used to use the `<f:param>` in a `<p:commandLink>` as follows:

```
<f:param name="index" value="#{rowIndex}" />
```

However, in my case with `<p:rowEditor>`, how can I get the row index when the user validates the edited value in the `onParameterValueEdit()` method?

```
public void onParameterValueEdit(RowEditEvent event) {  
    int index = ... // index of the row to which the edited cell belongs    
    parametersValue.set(Integer.parseInt(index),paramValue);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you need to know about it?

Comment: Wait... Your input/output values are bound to the backing bean instead  of to the iterated row object of the data model! How does that make sense? You should use `value="#{datasetParamDt.paramValue}"` instead of `value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.paramValue}"`. I wonder if that now removes the need to know about the row index.

Comment: yes this my problem the paramValue is not an attribute in the DataSet Class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This design makes no sense. Just bind the component value to the `parametersValue` list directly.

```
<h:outputText value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.parametersValue[rowIndex]}" />
...
<p:inputText value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.parametersValue[rowIndex]}" />
```

This way you also don't need to know about the row index anymore and you perhaps also don't need those action listener methods anymore. I'd only rename the property name to `parameterValues` to fix improper English.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, even though you aren't using any validation here, but since you mentioned the word "validate", I'd like to add that that validation should be performed by normal validators, not by action(listener) methods. Use the `required` or `validator` attribute, or the `<f:validator>` or `<f:validateXxx>` tags.